# regex: Finding a pattern of alternating numbers and strings

Tags: c++, regex, regex-group

I'm trying to find the following pattern:

(NUMBERS)(STRING)(NUMBERS)(STRING)(NUMBERS)(STRING)

with at least one group of (NUMBERS)(STRING) present. I also want to get in the match the number and the string separately.

Example:

```
1234abc234qwy2342nioo
23oin234noik32342noi
234nio234koi2341nio
```

The output I want is as follows:

1. 1234, abc, 234, qwy, 2342, nioo
2. 23, oin, 234, noik, 32342, noi

However, if the input is just a number, I don't want it to match with the pattern.

I came up with the following regex:

```
^(\d*)([a-z]*)(\d*)([a-z]*)(\d*)([a-z]*)$
```

[Regex Example](https://regex101.com/r/gKHkrL/2)

However, now it captures if I give it a number alone as well. For example, it matches the following patterns:

2342324

Is there a way I can impose on the regex that it captures at least one group of (NUMBERS)(STRINGS) and not match the numbers alone.

Comment: @IronMan I want to capture a (NUMBES)(STRING) in the group separately as well. Your regex captures the group as a whole.

Comment: Hi, perhaps you could use (?:(\d+)([a-z]+))+. That requires one or more digits then one more letters. And finally, one or more instances of that sequential pattern

Comment: Just use `[0-9]+[a-zA-Z]+` and match all occurrences in the string. Or do you also need to pre-validate string format before extraction? Then you will have to do it in two steps.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you wish to capture each substring of digits and each substring of letters in each line, except when the line contains only digits or only letters, in which nothing should be captured?

Comment: @CarySwoveland I guess you got it right. I have added example output in the question now. I'm sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the `*`, which means zero-or-more.  In other words, if you use `*`, it's essentially optional.  `+` means one-or-more, so that's more appropriate in your case.  For instance:

```
^(\d+[a-z]+){1,3}$
```

Or, if you want to retain the capture groups:

```
^(?:(\d+)([a-z]+)){1,3}$
```

Or:

```
^(\d+)([a-z]+)(?:(\d+)([a-z]+))?(?:(\d+)([a-z]+))?$
```

Comment: I want to have the number as well as the string extracted out as well. I have updated the question. Your regex matches the group of a number and a string.

Comment: @ubaabd I updated my answer.  Does that address your concern about capture groups?

Comment: I ran your first and second regex. However, it only returns the last (NUMBER)(STRING) group. For example, for the first input 234abc234qwy2342nioo, it outputs 2342 and nioo only and not other groups. I have updated the question with example output.

Comment: It does capture them all.  If you aren't getting all of them when you're reading the group values from the resulting match, then the problem is likely in your match-reading code.  Perhaps if you shared that code we could help.

Comment: Looks like ^(?:([0-9]+)([a-z]+))(?:([0-9]*)([a-z]*))(?:([0-9]*)([a-z]*))$ works just fine. It will require at least one (NUMBER)(STRING) group and optionally match two more occurrences.

Comment: Please see https://regex101.com/r/B3Z9EG/1 as it gives only the last group as outputs.

Comment: Ok.  That must be a limitation of your regex engine, then.  Some engines allow you to read all of the captures from each group.  Sorry for causing confusion.  Anyway, that's why I included the last pattern, so that it would work as similarly to your original as possible, regardless of how you're reading the results out.

Comment: I got similar results in C++ regex engine as well. Yes, the last regex works everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the regular expression

```
/(?:(?<=\D)\d+|\d+(?=\D))|\D+/
```

This will match alternating substrings of digits only and non-digits only, provided the string contains at least one non-digit character. If there are only digits in the string no match is made. If there is at least one non-digit character there will be one or more matches of non-digits and zero or more matches of digits.

We can make the regular expression self-documenting by writing it in *free-spacing mode*

```
/
(?:        # begin a non-capture group
  (?<=\D)  # next match is preceded by a non-digit character
  \d+      # match 1+ digits
  |        # or
  \d+      # match 1+ digits      
  (?=\D)   # previous match is followed by a non-digit character
)          # end non-capture group
|          # or
\D+        # match 1+ non-digit characters 
/x         # free-spacing regex definition mode
```

`(?<=\D)` is a *positive lookbehind*. `(=\D)` is a *positive lookahead*.

If, in addition, no match is to be made if the string contains only non-digit characters, the regex would be changed to the following:

```
/(?:(?<=\D)\d+|\d+(?=\D))|(?:(?<=d)\D+|\D+(?=\d))/
```